# stl priority queue based on lower value first

Tags: c++, stl

I have a problem with stl priority queue.I want to have the priority queue in the increasing 
order,which is decreasing by default.Is there any way to do this in priority queue.

And what is the complexity of building stl priority queue.If i use quick sort in an array which takes O(nlgn) is its complexity is similar to using priority queue???

Plz someone ans.Advanced thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a different comparator as the 3rd template argument of `std::priority_queue`.

priority_queue is a container adaptor that works on any sequence you define. The performance of insertion is equal to the `std::push_heap` operation and takes logarithmic time. So the complexity to sorting after all insertions are done isn't equal. If you insert a fixed amount and work the queue afterwards a `vector` and a single `sort` could be more efficient.

Answer (score 30):

1. `priority_queue` has template parameters that specify the container type and the comparison to use for ordering. By default, the comparison is `less<T>`; to get the opposite ordering, use `priority_queue<T, vector<T>, greater<T>>`.
2. Insertion into a priority queue takes logarithmic time, so building a queue of `N` items has complexity `O(N logN)`, the same as building and sorting a vector. But once it's built, insertion into the priority queue is still logarithmic, while insertion into a sorted vector is linear.

Comment: Infact i am new in stl.so plz give me an example of priority queue.
like i have used as  priority_queue<int>Q so  what should be the constructor when (priority_queue<T, vector<T>, greater<T>>) is used.i will be greatful if u give the actual code.thanx agin for ur help.

Comment: Ok ,thanx everyone who helped me.I got the answer.


std::priority_queue<int,std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >,std::greater<int> > Q;

Comment: what is the point of the second argument ? can't it be like set where we just go set<int, greater<int>> and not set<int, vector<list<int>>, greater<int>> ?

Answer (score 10):

Use the type

```
priority_queue<T, vector<T>, greater<T> >
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just push values multiplying them by -1 so it will be stored in reverse order unlike the actual default order...and multiply the value with -1 again while retrieving data to get it in its actual form.

Answer (score 0):

Replace **T** bellow with variable type. You will get your work done

```
priority_queue<T, vector<T>, greater<T> > PQ;
```

As example for **int** type variable you can write it like this:

```
priority_queue<int, vector<int>, greater<int> > Q;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use comparator class/struct to achieve the same in priority queue.

```
class CompareHeight 
{ 
    public:
        bool operator()(int &p1, int &p2) 
        {
            return p1 > p2; 
        } 
};
```

Now declare the priority queue as

```
priority_queue<int, vector<int>, CompareHeight> pq;
```