# Priority Queue implementation - logical error in C++?

Tags: c++, priority-queue

I'm trying to compare hsld (integer) in a structure called AdjList.
This is the function to be used for comparisons when entering pointers to the priority queue.

```
struct CompareHSLD
{
    bool operator()(AdjList* const p1, AdjList* const p2)
    {
        return p1->hsld < p2->hsld;
    }
};
```

This is the priority queue declaration.

```
priority_queue<AdjList*, vector<AdjList*>, CompareHSLD> PriQueueAdj;
```

Unable to figure out what the error is in this implementation. There is no syntax error but the priority queue doesn't seem to be sorted. It pops out the wrong elements.

Should it be `p1->hsld > p2.hsld` if I want to pop the lowest value elements first?

Comment: Probably not the reason, but shouldn't it be `bool operator()(const AdjList* p1, const AdjList* p2) const`

Comment: Nope, wasn't the reason.

Comment: Yes, use `>` if you want the smallest at the top (i.e., a min-heap).

Comment: possible duplicate of [stl priority queue based on lower value first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851384/stl-priority-queue-based-on-lower-value-first)

Comment: Since this works in a minimal example, I'd say the context in which you see the problem demonstrates the issue. From what we see here, you're on the right track. Expand the question with something that shows the problem when we try it out here.

Comment: T.C. answered it, I guess. I tried it out (as edited later). It worked. Yes, it was the min-heap max-heap confusion. Thanks.